# add a column to a dataframe created with sliced columns in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have the following df:

```
KSCHL01     VTEXT01         KWERT01     KSCHL02     VTEXT02                 KWERT02     KSCHL03     VTEXT03         KWERT03     id
ZBTB        Tarif de base   4455.00     ZBFA        Brut facturé            4455.00     ZBN Brut    Négocié         3645.00     1
ZBT         Brut Tarif.     222.75      ZFIF        Remises fin d'ordre     0.00        ZMAJ        Majorations     0.00        2
```

I want to slice its columns and transform them to lines, this is the desired output:

```
id  KSCHL   VTEXT                   KWERT
1   ZBTB    Tarif de base           4455.00
1   ZBFA    Brut facturé            4455.00
1   ZBN     Brut Négocié            3645.00
2   ZBT     Brut Tarif.             222.75
2   ZFIF    Remises fin d'ordre     0.00
2   ZMAJ    Majorations             0.00
```

This is what I did:

```
for( i <- 0 to df.columns.length-4 by 3){
  var temp=df.select(df.columns.slice(i, i+3).map(col(_)): _*)
  val columns = temp.columns
  val regex = """[0-9]"""
  val replacingColumns = columns.map(regex.r.replaceAllIn(_, "")) # delete all digits in column names
  val resultDF = replacingColumns.zip(columns).foldLeft(temp){(tempdf, name) => tempdf.withColumnRenamed(name._2, name._1)}
  res=res.union(resultDF) # Append df to final DF
}
```

This works fine but does not include the id column for all lines. It returns the desired output but without id column.

I tried to add this after declaring temp dataframe:

```
temp = temp.withColumn("id", df.id)
```

but I had this error:

```
error: value id in class Dataset cannot be accessed in org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Any idea why please ? And what is the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native Spark solution

```scala
df.withColumn("c1", map(lit("a"), 'vtext01, lit("b"), 'kwert01))
 .withColumn("c2", map(lit("a"), 'vtext02, lit("b"), 'kwert02))
 .withColumn("c3", map(lit("a"), 'vtext03, lit("b"), 'kwert03))
 .withColumn("flipped", explode(array('c1, 'c2, 'c3)))
 .withColumn("vtext", map_values('flipped)(0)) 
 .withColumn("kwert", map_values('flipped)(1)) 
 .drop("c1", "c2", "c3", "flipped")
```

It creates a key value map for each of the v and k combinations, then explodes them (so triples the rows).  Then it takes the values in those maps to put back into the final vtext and kwert columns.

Comment: what if the number of columns is dynamic ?

Comment: It will still work.  You'll need to provide more details as to what you mean by dynamic. Will the number of ci columns just be some number 1...x? Will the vtexti, kwerti and ci all be aligned, or will there be something like a c7 that uses vtext03 and kwert11?  If it's the first one, it's still fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

First you create 3 dataframes based on this dataframe

```
val df1 = df.select(col("KSCHL01").as("KSCHL"), col("VTEXT01").as("VTEXT"), col("KWERT01").as("KWERT"), col("id"))
```

Output

```
KSCHL       VTEXT           KWERT       id
ZBTB        Tarif de base   4455.00      1
ZBT         Brut Tarif.     222.75       2
```

Then

```
val df2 = df.select(col("KSCHL02").as("KSCHL"), col("VTEXT02").as("VTEXT"), col("KWERT02").as("KWERT"), col("id"))
```

Output

```
KSCHL       VTEXT                   KWERT       id
ZBFA        Brut facturé            4455.00     1
ZFIF        Remises fin d'ordre     0.00        2
```

Then

```
val df3 = df.select(col("KSCHL03").as("KSCHL"), col("VTEXT03").as("VTEXT"), col("KWERT03").as("KWERT"), col("id"))
```

Output

```
 KSCHL       VTEXT          KWERT       id
 ZBN Brut    Négocié        3645.00     1
 ZMAJ        Majorations    0.00        2
```

Then you can apply an union on these three dataframes

```
val finalDataframe = df1.union(df2).union(df3)
finalDataframe.show()
```

Output

```
id  KSCHL   VTEXT                   KWERT
1   ZBTB    Tarif de base           4455.00
1   ZBFA    Brut facturé            4455.00
1   ZBN     Brut Négocié            3645.00
2   ZBT     Brut Tarif.             222.75
2   ZFIF    Remises fin d'ordre     0.00
2   ZMAJ    Majorations             0.00
```

Comment: what if the number of columns is dynamic ?